What is the difference between using a Concept directly instead of `typename`, versus using the `requires` keyword? Or is it just a matter of style?
I'm trying to wrap my head around concepts in C++20.  Consider the following (very simple) concept:
template <typename T>
concept Float = requires
{
    std::floating_point<T>;
};

I can write a templated class using this concept in 2 ways:
template <Float T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T val) : value{ val } {};
private:
    T value;
};

Or I can do
template <typename T> requires Float<T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T val) : value{ val } {};
private:
    T value;
};

In this particular example, these behave exactly the same.  Is this always the case though?  Are there situations where it is easier to express some constraint using the template <...> requires ... syntax?  Or is this merely a style preference/convention?
The only thing I can think of right now is that using the template <...> requires ... syntax may allow you represent relational constraints between multiple template arguments, where as the template <CONCEPT T> syntax only allows you to represent a constraint on a single argument?
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

There is no difference between:
template <Float T>

and
template <typename T> requires Float<T>

They mean the same thing. If you declare a template and then define it later, you have to use the same syntax in both places - but both syntaxes do mean the same thing.
It's purely a matter of preference. The type-constraint syntax is more limited (can only be used to constrain a type) but can be more readable.
Note that the type-constraint syntax can express multi-type constraints. For instance the typical ranges pattern of:
template <typename I, typename S>
    requires input_iterator<I>
         and sentinel_for<S, I>
void algo(I, S);

can be written with the shorthand:
template <input_iterator I, sentinel_for<I> S>
void algo(I, S);


Ahh this was actually something I was wondering about separately: how to handle concepts/requirements when declaring and defining templates in different places.  This is good to know the syntax needs to match (though, somewhat annoying it needs to be handled in both spots, as especially for a large class, this makes it super unwieldy to declare in a .hpp and later define in a .ipp

interestingly, gcc allows using two constraint forms interchangeably in declaration and definition, requiring them to match semantically, rather than lexically. Since gcc is the only one of three major compilers that allows that it's probably an extension, not the standard requirement: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zzvded9ro

Using concept names in place of typenames is always a shorthand for something you could do in long-form. However, there are some circumstances where the long-form equivalent is more unwieldy.
For example:
template <Concept auto value>
class foo {...};

//becomes

template <auto value> requires Concept<decltype(value)>
class foo {...};

